# Identify the video codec

Tags: browser, html5-video, codec

I have created a app to integrate popular video services (Youtube, Dailymotion and Facebook). All the videos are played in html5 format. When the video plays in a html5 compatible browser, I want to know the codec of the video being played.

e.g. Youtube videos are played in h.264 format on Safari whereas on Firefox and Chrome it uses vp8/vp9. This can be identified by the stats provided by Youtube

I want to identify the codecs for other services on these specific browsers. How can I do that?